# Почему после сканера не открывается диалоговое окно

Tags: java

```
    Scanner i=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=i.nextLine();

    String path="";
    JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    int r=chooser.showDialog(null,"Выбрать файл");
    if(r==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file=chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        path=file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    System.out.println(path);
```

После ввода строки в консольном приложении не открывается окно для выбора файла, но если сканера нет, то все ок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Метод `nextLine()` ждет, когда Вы введете что-либо в консоль
2. Перед появлением `JFileChooser`, происходит задержка (1-10 сек), поэтому следует подождать
3. Подождав 1-10 секунд, попробуйте нажать <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, и посмотреть, не появилось ли окно, если оно не появилось, подождите еще и повторите этот пункт